# Attach sphere at the center of the device screen when moving

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

I am trying to attach a sphere at the center of the device screen and as I move the device around the sphere should stay in the centre of the screen (like a crosshair)

I have attached a sphere entity and added it to sphere_anchor like this in makeUIView function
**sphere_anchor.addChild(modelEntity)**

But as i move my device the sphere  just moves in the initial frame the entity was attached to as I move the device.Hoping someone could point me to the correct way of doing this

```
//Implement ARSession didUpdate session delegate method
public func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
    
    let trasnform =  frame.camera.transform

    if ((self.scene.findEntity(named: "sphere")) != nil) {
        let position = simd_make_float3(trasnform.columns.3)
             //print(position)
         sphere_anchor.position = position
         sphere_anchor.orientation = Transform(matrix: trasnform).rotation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `AnchorEntity(.camera)`. If you implement it there's no need for `session(_:didUpdate:)` instance method because RealityKit's anchor automatically tracks ARCamera position.

```
@IBOutlet var arView: ARView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let mesh = MeshResource.generateSphere(radius: 0.1)
    let sphere = ModelEntity(mesh: mesh)

    let anchor = AnchorEntity(.camera)

    sphere.setParent(anchor)
    arView.scene.addAnchor(anchor)
    
    sphere.transform.translation.z = -0.75
}
```

`AnchorEntity(.camera)` works only when real iOS device in **`Active Scheme`** is chosen.

[image]

Comment: I didn't know if I should ask a new ques, since it relates to the above answer-

I wish to do a raycast from the position of the sphere to check if it intersects with any AR objects in the scene. (Much like if a crosshair was on top of any object in the scene) 

To use raycast I need the 2D position of the sphere in the view’s coordinate system. I understand the `project(SIMD3<Float>) -> CGPoint?` method converts the 3D world coordinate system of the scene to the 2D pixel coordinate and not the normalised view coordinates. 

Is there a way to do the above or this is an incorrect approach

Comment: @anahom, publish it as another question, please.

Comment: Hello, I posted a new question as suggested 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65814249/implement-a-crosshair-kind-behaviour-in-arkit